# git - how to synchronize initially uncontrolled copies without re-transmitting them?

Tags: git

I have separate copies of a large dataset (multiple TB) at different sites.  I thought it would be read-only but now the team wants to be able to share edits.  So I would like to place them under version control in git, but without re-transmitting the dataset itself.  Then we could use git-bundle to make small delta files to transmit changes.

Ideally, I could independently 'git init; git add *' the dataset at each site, and since the dataset copies are identical, the initial commits would have identical checksums and everything would be fine, but I haven't been able to get that to happen.

If I could delete the git blobs corresponding to files in my dataset without deleting references to them (thus creating a 'corrupt' bundle) and adding them back in on the other side that would be great, but I can't find low-level commands to do that.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The git commits won't be the same on two sites unless everything that it hashes is exactly the same.  That means the date on the commit, the author, the contents of all the files in the commit, the parent commit (if any), and maybe other things that I can't think of.

You could try fixing those things with `git commit --date=<some date> --author=<some author>` and see if that is sufficient to get the commits to match.  I don't know if that will work, but it's worth a try.

This does sound like it's going to be painful in the long run though.  Git isn't really designed for tracking multi-terabyte files.  I think you're going to push yourself into a corner.  You could look at git-annex or git-lfs and see if those are better suited for your needs.  Or maybe you need to invent some delta description method of your own, and only store the deltas in git.

Comment: Thanks.  At your suggestion I tried specifying the date and author during commit, on a test on small directory copied using cp -pR (to preserve dates), but it did not result in identical (equal checksum) commits.